# In Unity3D is it possible to keep the Scene view focused when hitting Play?

Tags: ide, unity-game-engine

In Unity3D, when you hit play, by default, it switches to the full 'Game' view which is great for previewing and such, but sometimes we just want to see our results in the 'Scene' view since we don't have to worry about setting up all the lighting, materials, etc.

Now we know we can simply create a new layout that shows both the 'Game' and the 'Scene' tabs at the same time, and that's what we're doing so we can continue to look at the 'Scene' tab when we start.  However, we just don't want to see the 'Game' tab at all.  Love to just hide it until we need it later.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The game scene can't be closed while running the game. But I found a little workaround: You can detach the Game view into a separate window make it as small as possible and position it near the play button like this:

[image]

Now after you hit the play button just click into the empty area left from the play button as soon as the game view gets the focus. It's faster than running with your mouse to the tabs. On the other side if you are a keyboard junkie like me hit CMD+P, CMD+< on Mac or the equivalent on Windows.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't too different from what we're doing except we're still leaving it in its own tab 'area' (separate from the 'scene' tab) and we just make it really, really small.  That way we don't even need to click elsewhere.  We just ignore it.  Still, since there isn't an actual way to do this, I'll give you the answer.

Comment: @Kay Command + <?  Do you mean Command+~?  As much as I like the speed of keyboard shortcuts and trackpad gestures, I usually just put the Game and Scene View in the same panel, so that when I click the Scene Tab, the Game View takes up no real estate at all, and I don't need to keep track of its panel.  The Game View only needs to be visible upon play; it can be hidden "behind" any other tab thereafter.

Comment: @Jessy [keyboard] Seems like shortcuts are locale dependent - not really a surprise. In German it's something like "Move Focus to Next Window" like you do for cycling through all open finder windows. Alternatively you can use CMD+1 in Unity to get to the scene view provided that you don't use for navigating between spaces (I reconfigured spaces navigation and use ALT+1 or ALT+2 now to use CMD+1.... for application specific shortcuts).

Comment: @Jessy [panels] That's the way I understood MarqueIV is using it now. It's fine for keyboard oriented users. My proposal was targeting on mouse oriented users, because it's faster to move the mouse just a few milimeters than 20 centimeters to switch the tab.

Answer (score 20):

Place this component on any *GameObject* and set the `KeepSceneViewActive` field to `true`.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class KeepSceneAlive : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool KeepSceneViewActive;

    void Start()
    {
        if (this.KeepSceneViewActive && Application.isEditor)
        {
            UnityEditor.SceneView.FocusWindowIfItsOpen(typeof(UnityEditor.SceneView));
        }
    }
}
```